# Swift Json Error

Tags: json, swift

I was trying to pull data from **kimono** I was encountered error. My kimono api's link = https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/8dfvxr3a?apikey=5747a54d5ca762895b474cc224943240

and Xcode error is

`"thread 3: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode0x0)"`

How can I fix this error ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var ara: UITextField!
@IBAction func getir(sender: AnyObject) {

    araIMDB()
}

func araIMDB(){

        var urlYol = NSURL(string: "http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/8dfvxr3a?apikey=5747a54d5ca762895b474cc224943240")
        var oturum = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var task = oturum.dataTaskWithURL(urlYol!){

            data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil){

                println(error)

            }
            var jsonError : NSError?
            var jsonSonuc  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as Dictionary<String, String>
            if( jsonError != nil)
            {
                println(jsonError)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.titleLabel.text = jsonSonuc["count"]
            }
          }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown at `as Dictionary<String, String>`, because your JSON is not flat dictionary. In your case, you should cast it to `NSDictionary` or `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>` using [optional form of the type cast operator (`as?`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_514).

You don't need `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers`, because you only read from the result.

`jsonSonuc["count"]` is integer value, not string. you should cast it to `Int` using `as? Int`, then covert it to `String`.

Try:

```
        var jsonError: NSError?
        var jsonSonuc = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .allZeros, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary
        if( jsonError != nil) {
            println(jsonError)
        }
        else if let count = jsonSonuc?["count"] as? Int {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.titleLabel.text = String(count)
            }
        }
```